# How to hide McAfee site advisor icon from firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

My work machine comes with McAfee siteadvisor installed and it places the most inconvenient icon in firefox
[image]

This makes  it very difficult to add new tabs or navigate to the tabs right under the button.
I do not have the permission to disable the button, also I do not want to enable the menu bar as suggested in the McAfee forums.

Comment: Why don't you just reconfigure the location of the plugin?  I can tell you without the permission to disable it, you likely won't be able to, hide the icon.  Why are you against using the menu bar solution?

Comment: I tried customizing the toolbar layout but the button wont budge,I am using menu bar right now but I don't like being forced to change my ways because of some ill conceived code.

Comment: In an ideal world you would simply disable it.  Since you don't have permission to do that, your options are limited, and likely simply a limitation of the plugin's lack configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out :
Install the firefox plugin Stylish and add the following script to it -

```
/*
 * Do not remove the @namespace line -- it's required for correct functioning
 */
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"); /* set default namespace to XUL */

#saff-toolbar-items {
    display:none !important;
    visibility:hidden !important;
    }
```

[Source](http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2009/09/moving-immovable-that-mcafee.html)